# How to achieve delegation or composition using Ember-data

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to delegate all calls to App.Item to App.Book, so that i can do App.Book.name and it returns the value of App.Item.name and thesame for App.Book.position. Simply put a way to delegate all the attributes of App.Item to App.Book, imagine a scenario where App.Item has 10 - 12 attributes.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: "foo" })
  position: DS.attr('string')
});


App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  category: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: I have'nt done this, but does it work if you declare App.Book as a sublass of App.Item ? I mean `App.Book = App.Item.extend({...})`

Comment: Thanks. I will see if i can redesign the various model i have to see if your suggestion will work. My original plan was for the book model to access the Items model through Account model. I tried to simplify my question to focus on the delegation bit, since i was going to delegate Item model to account. If it works, i will come back and accept your answer. Thanks.